# AngularUI Bootstrap Modal with Video flickers while loading

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to display an AngularUI based Bootstrap Modal window which has embedded YouTube videos in iframes. Everything works fine but while loading the modal window flickers at least once before the entire modal content is loaded.

From whatever I researched I can understand that Bootstrap modal opens up before the contents are loaded completely and the iframes in which the Youtube videos are embedded is causing it.

Any idea why this is happening and suggestions to avoid the flicker will be appreciated.

Comment: sharing some code would be helpful

Comment: Have you tried ng-cloak? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1):

adding ng-cloak to the template used for the dialog fixed the same issue for me.

Comment: Please explain, why this solves the issue (and what the core issue is). Posting result of randomly trying things isn't very useful.

Comment: ng-cloak worked for me, just as @Jose wrote in his answer. This is because ng-cloak prevents "the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display."
I jus quoted from here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak